# Shell sha1($salt.$password) error

Tags: bash, string-concatenation, command-substitution

I try to do something like this directly on my console as some testruns :

It does not seem to work.. any idea what is the mistake I am doing

```
salt="3245678906789045689"
password="12321312231"
blub=`sha1($salt.$password)`
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$salt.$password'
-bash: command substitution: line 1: `sha1($salt.$password)'
```

It throws out an errors
this is what I intend to do at the end:

```
echo $blub
```

Can some one please helpout as to what is the error I am doing?

Comment: I would guess that you have an syntax error near `($salt.$password)`. Did you want `sha1 "$salt.$password"`

Comment: yes. That's is what im  trying to achieve.

Comment: if you want to concatenate `$salt` and `$password` do
`"$salt$password"`.
if `sha1` is a function or another bash-script call it
`sha1 "$salt$password"`

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke: Can I generate a sha1 with the concatenated string of $salt$password?.

Comment: dont know how `sha1` works. if its meant to be two separate arguments to the function (make probably more sense) then call it
`sha1 $salt $password`

Comment: `sha1 "$salt$pass"
No command 'sha1' found, did you mean:
 Command 'shar' from package 'sharutils' (main)
sha1: command not found`

That's the error that is being thrown

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you want to use SHA1 from the [OpenSSL package](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html). 
This should be already installed on your system.

```
echo -n "$salt$password" | openssl dgst -sha1
(stdin)= a1b2ce5a82e18f454db6b2d6ee82533914f90337
```

To capture just the sha1-digest:

```
blub=`echo -n "$salt$password" | openssl dgst -sha1 |awk '{print $NF}'`
echo $blub
a1b2ce5a82e18f454db6b2d6ee82533914f90337
```

I assume you copied your code from **PHP**. There functions are called with brackets and the `.`-Operator concatenates strings. In that interpretation my code is the exact equivalent of your code in **BASH**.

Comment: why does it have to say that it is the standard input stream. when we already know it. :) Can't we kill that part of it

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I could get it diectly. But, why does it show . Just a small question

Answer (score 1):

I didn't came across a lot of explanations on how to easily do a SHA checksum in bash and put it in a variable in the right way, at the same time we should not use sha1 anymore, but something more difficult to bruteforce, like sha512:

```
dash=`echo -n $password$salt|sha512sum` ##gives hash with trailing dash
read hash rest <<< "$dash" ##removes trailing dash and gives $hash
echo $hash
6555b9d2331203634664f48f604b59372b32badbc115ec6b2586890ef4d3a6b6816d84cc424cdfc538f6a7ccf664c90caeeb942dbf7953051bb1d7414a191c51
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider adding more details to this answer and explain what the OP was doing wrong and why your solution works.